# How to switch the primary iCloud account on my iPhone 4?

Tags: itunes, ios, icloud

I have recently upgraded an iPhone 4 to iOS 5.1 and when asked i registered it with Account A for both iCloud & iTunes.

However i also use Account A on my iPhone 4S and thus wish to switch the the iCloud account to a brand new Account B (keeping Account A for iTunes as all the apps are purchased on it).

Is this possible? The iCloud screen in settings does not let me change the Apple ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open the **Mail, Contacts, Calendars** section and find the iCloud
   account.
2. Select it.
3. Press "Delete Account".
4. Select "Delete".
5. Select "Add Account…"
6. Select "iCloud".
7. Log in.

This works on iPad; I assume it's the same for all other current iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but does it delete the account permanently.  The old icloud account is on my other phone that I still want to keep.